# Fill the input time with current time using Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have this input

```
<input type="time" [(ngModel)]="post.time" value="{{selectedTime}}"
                               formControlName="scheduled-time">
```

The time looks like this:

--:--:--

How can I make the default is the current time?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483479/angular-how-to-set-input-of-time-type-to-current-time-on-initialization

Answer (score 3):

In constructor set `post.time` to string of the value. i.e `21:37`

Here's demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vk4kyc

*Remember that hours and minutes must have 2 digits*

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value by assigning value (eg. '15:30') to your ngModel property

For more details: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Also, I don't understand why you have ngModel, formControlName and value being used at the same time. You need only one of these at any time